# Posting similarly worded questions on meta - how?

Tags: support, best-of

I was about to post the Q3 installment of the "best of" series when I was prevented by the system. It doesn't allows me posting because it recognizes the question to be a "duplicate" of some previous post.

[image]

Admittedly, and on purpose, the working is near-identical except that the dates are changed. This hasn't been a problem previously, though.

How can I overcome this hurdle? Moderators?

Comment: Are you sure that you edited the "2018" to "2019" in the title before posting? I've only had this error when the titles are EXACTLY the same.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes, sure. I've just tried it again, same thing.

Comment: It [let me do it](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6775/best-puzzles-of-2019-q3-july-september) just now. Possibly it was triggered by the fact that you tried to post Q2 & Q3 in short succession which increased the spam detection?