# Best puzzles of 2019 Q3 (July - September)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> ### What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the third quarter ( July / August / September ) 2019?

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

> Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):
>
> - Algorithmically selected "best of":
>
>   - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2019 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2019&month=07#query-results)
>   - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2019 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/871694/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2019&month=07#query-results)
> - Best by votes/views:
>
>   - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2019 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2019/07/01#query-results)
>   - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2019 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2019/07/01#query-results)
>   - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2019 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2019/07/01#query-results)

---

<sub>Meta-meta issues:</sub>

- <sub>Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?</sub>

  - <sub>Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-fi/Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3142/31394) do something very similar.</sub>
- <sub>What's the point?</sub>

  - <sub>To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.</sub>
  - <sub>To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.</sub>
  - <sub>To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.</sub>

Answer (score 14):

### [Magic Maze Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89482/magic-maze-puzzle), by boboquack

I would like to nominate this puzzle (Sep 2019), which gave me one of the best feelings of a job well done when I finally solved it! The puzzle itself is DIFFICULT, and not just something you can glance at while passing - it required real commitment to attempting to solve it (in fact, I had to put aside a couple of hours to do so).

The thought that went into designing it (and ensuring it had a single, unique solution) was, frankly, tremendous - as evidenced by its difficulty. It was nicely designed and illustrated, well explained, and a real test of logical deduction. I can only imagine how long it took to create!

For the record, I genuinely did print out and cut up the page as recommended, and got plenty of odd looks in the library while working through it on the table top! It constantly made you think about six moves ahead of yourself (sometimes even 20 or 30!) and the effort that went into planning and creating it truly deserves to be acknowledged...

Comment: If you didn't nominate this one, I was going to! It was a *lot* of fun to solve, and it's clear that a lot of thought went into its construction.

Comment: @Deusovi Reading back what I've written above, I realise that not once did I even mention 'fun' - but I totally should have! It felt like the kind of board game you buy because you played it as a group once and enjoyed it, *and then* once you get it home you discover it plays amazingly in solitaire as well, and you wonder why you ever thought you needed friends to have a good time!! :)